# Kryo vs Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, kryo

I am checking Java Serialization, Kryo and Jackson.

I have created some tiny code which serialize random objects N times. I measure the time to serialize and deserialize and the size of the object.

I'm not pretty happy about the size Kryo vs Jackson, I've been reading about benchmarks and people got a lot of difference between Kryo and Jackson, but, I just got about 5-10% less in Kryo. I don't know if I missed something on my code.

This is my code to Kryo:

```
public static byte[] writeAsBytes(final Object oObject) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Output output = new Output(bos);
        kryo2.register(Event.class, 0);
        kryo2.writeClassAndObject(output, oObject);
        output.close();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }


    public static <T> T read(final byte[] aObject, final Class<T> clazz) {
        T oObject;
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(aObject);
        Input input = new Input(is);
        kryo2.register(clazz, 0);
        oObject = (T) kryo2.readClassAndObject(input);
        input.close();

        return oObject;
    }
```

I tried registering the objects and without registering, I got the same size and the time was similar as well.

How could I improve the size with Kryo?? The size and times I got:

```
Size java:5245
Size jackson:5076
Size kryo:4790
14/09/22 12:18:05 INFO util.TimerUtil: DesSerializar Jackson:25135ms,Counter:10001
14/09/22 12:18:05 INFO util.TimerUtil: DesSerializar Java:2637ms,Counter:10001
14/09/22 12:18:05 INFO util.TimerUtil: DesSerializar Kryo:396ms,Counter:10001
14/09/22 12:18:05 INFO util.TimerUtil: Serializar Jackson:985ms,Counter:10001
14/09/22 12:18:05 INFO util.TimerUtil: Serializar Java:1171ms,Counter:10001
14/09/22 12:18:05 INFO util.TimerUtil: Serializar Kryo:397ms,Counter:10001
```

I execute a lot of times the code, and I surprise about the deserializing time for Jackson, 25000ms???

Comment: Please include class definition: your question is meaningless without knowing kind of objects you are dealing with.
For example: if most of the data are just `String`s, size (and performance) differences should be small. And for other data types like floating-point numbers, differences can add up. And for performance benchmarking you really should have a look at a tool like `jmh` to get reliable numbers. As to Jackson deserialization, test code itself needs to not only do warmups (which `jmh` can do) but also ensure to always reuse `ObjectMapper` instances.

Comment: if you have some strings there in the object it won't make much difference, but kryo has some support for compression. why are you wondering about  slow Jackson? it serializes in json, text based serialization will always be much slower than binary one

Comment: @MarianP depends on definition "much slower"; typically speed will converge to difference in encoded size; meaning that binary formats may be up to twice as fast. But implementation differences mean that variation is high.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `kryo.readObject(arg0, arg1)` instead of `kryo.readClassAndObject(input);` it serializes objects in Java more effectively.

Comment: I'm curious how that turned out.  Maybe i'll try it.